# My motherboard ethernet is incompatible with the ethernet switch I bought. Why is that? How do I know which switch to buy?

Tags: motherboard, ethernet, network-adapter

I bought [this ethernet switch](https://www.newegg.com/tp-link-tl-sg1005d-5-x-rj45/p/N82E16833704042?Item=N82E16833704042) to provide wired internet to my whole house:
It worked great until I bought a new computer ([link to motherboard](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-A320M-S2H-rev-1x#kf)). The computer doesn't have a WiFi card (it was a cheap DIY) so I have to use an ethernet cable. But the computer gets no connection.

What I've tried:

- I have another computer that I hooked up to the ethernet in the same way and that works.
- When I wire the ethernet to [my WiFi router](https://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/wnr2020.aspx) first, then an ethernet cable out of the router to my new computer, it works. It's only when the ethernet cable comes directly from the ethernet switch that it has the error messages. The error messages I get tell me my ethernet adapter is incompatible.
- [Ethernet status page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/care7.png)
- [What I get from the troubleshooter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1U7R.png)
- I went through bunch of tutorials trying to reset my ethernet adapter, my TCP/IP connection, etc. and nothing worked.
- I thought it may be because my router is lower speed than my gigabit ethernet, but the motherboard specs say it is compatible with gigabit.

My best guess is that the motherboard ethernet adapter is not compatible with the switch somehow.

I'm probably going to buy another ethernet switch soon (because I need more ports) and I wanted to ask the community which one would be compatible with this motherboard, and why?

Comment: I didn't entirely understand your description of the layout of how things are connected so it's hard for me to tell what exactly the problem is - but I seriously doubt it's a "compatibility" issue. I think you may have misconfigured something, I wouldn't rush to buy a new Ethernet switch. If you have a USB stick - I would suggest trying to put some Live Linux distro on it, try to boot from the USB stick - and see if you have network connectivity. If you do, it will indicate this is a problem with Windows or how Windows is configured. If you don't, it might hint that it's an hardware issue

Comment: I agree with @omer . It's probably you and not your equipment.  You motherboard is not a "one off".. it is one of the premium Taiwan brands.. it is probably not your MB but your configuration.  Also.. worth fixing.. direct Ethernet is WAY WAY better than WiFi.

Comment: I'll definitely try out the Linux idea, but I thought I would clarify what I mean by my setup. My internet is provided by my HOA so I have no modem. The internet is wired directly into my house and that's why I need the ethernet switch to wire my internet to my few computers and my WiFi router. When I connect this new computer to my WiFi router via ethernet, I receive an ethernet connection. It is only when it is connected directly to the ethernet switch that I don't get a connection and that' what I'm asking about.

Comment: The switch should be placed "behind" your router, that is, between your router and your PC. You should plug the internet coming from your HOA directly into the router's WAN port, and then the switch (and any other wired computers) needs to be plugged into one of the router's LAN ports.

Comment: @SamForbis thank you for the suggestion, that actually worked. However, the point of this whole thing is that I want gigabit wired speeds for my computer and my router doesn't go that high (100mb). So I really just want to wire my computer directly to the switch. Which is exactly what I'm doing with my other computer and it works. It does make me realize that the switch isn't the issue. I'll report back later tonight when I have more time to try the Linux idea that omer gave.

Comment: You will need a new router, then. The router is your entire household's "gateway" to the internet, meaning the connection must go directly to the router's WAN port. Your router assigns private IP addresses and facilitates internet connection sharing between the devices in your home. You cannot place a switch between it and its internet connection (at least not in residential environments).

Comment: If you want Gigabit speed, then get a new router that has Gigabit LAN ports.  Your ISP is giving you only one IP address, which is being used by the router.  When you bypass the router, there is no access to the internet because your new PC has no IP address.  Booting Linux instead of Windows cannot change that problem.  @Sibee and SamForbis are giving you correct advice.  Simple test to prove that new switch and motherboard are not the problem: disconnect everything, and then only connect what you claim are the problem devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for answering so promptly and thoroughly. In the end, the solution was a combination of your answers.

What was happening is that like many people said, my HOA was only providing one IP address to my house. My router was able to use that IP to assign more IPs to my WiFi devices. I had my first computer connected to the ethernet bypassing the router, which I thought to mean I didn't need the router.

But what was actually happening, is that even though the computer wasn't wired to the router to use the DHCP pool of the router, it was connected via WiFi as the secondary connection so it was still being assigned an IP. The second computer didn't have a WiFi card, so when it bypassed the router it wasn't being assigned an IP address.

I have since bought a router that handles a gigabit connection and I have the switch connected to that, and all of my wired devices have blazing fast internet and valid IP addresses. I learned a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your 'Ethernet status page' shows that the cable is connected and working. Both ethernet adapters see eachother fine and have negotiated the full 1Gbps speed. So thats more than likely not the problem.

The problem is that your computer is not getting an IP address. Your computer is by default set to automatically obtain an IP address by DHCP. Your router is likely your DHCP server. Make sure that your router is connected (by wire) to the ethernet switch and your PC also has a wired connection to the switch.

Comment: Ya, what you are describing is essentially what I have set up already. That's exactly what doesn't work. When I plug the computer into the router, it does work, but gets much slower speeds so I want to fix this and plug my computer into the gigabit connection. My other computer works this way.

Comment: have you tried swapping switch ports with a known-working system? is your DHCP address pool larger than the number of clients you have?

Comment: How many computers do you have connected ? It might be that since you are connected through your HOA, they only hand out a limited amount of IP addresses per house/apartment. Your ethernet switch is unmanaged, which basicly means its operating at a layer that doesnt care about IP addresses. It's nothing more than a fancy splitting divice. Have you tried connecting the none working PC to the exact same cabling as the working PC ? Also, can you try not connecting the second PC for 24h+ before connecting the none working one ?

Comment: Yes I have tried plugging it in the same as the working machine and it still didn't work. It's not a problem with cords or the setup. I also tried removing all other devices and connecting only this computer. So it shouldn't be IP address amount limitations.